# Ionic Framework Data offline sync

Tags: node.js, api, ionic-framework

I am Trying to get some data to show in an ionic application,my problem that i want to know how to be able to get the data online,and then save them when iam offline,so i can consult some of them.
Any proposed solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to have a database on the phone that automatically syncs with an online database when the phone has signal then you should look at PouchDB and CouchDB. There is an excellent tutorial at https://www.joshmorony.com/offline-syncing-in-ionic-2-with-pouchdb-couchdb/ that you could read.

Comment: Thank you Mr Chris,CouchDB can be used for free? i dont know but i read somewhere its a little expensive to get.

Comment: No, it's an Open Source project. There are commercial providers who charge you for hosting. I have set this up myself on AWS on one of their free tiers. If you're not too familiar with doing this then sign up with Bitnami and then you can create an AWS instance using https://bitnami.com/stack/couchdb - they set everything up and it's very easy

Comment: Thank you it was so hrelpful

Comment: there are a similar tutorial with ionic 1?im not very familiar with ionic2 and typescript

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I would definitely recommend trying to learn ionic2 - it's the future (and the present!)

Comment: What if I want to use MySQL? any suggestion?